# vector удаление значений

Tags: c++, ооп, vector, stl

У меня есть класс tree, у него есть поле price. объекты класса я храню в vectore,
моя задача: пользователь вводит стоимость елки, и все елки, у которых есть такая цена, должны быть удалены. (Объекты из вектора).
Мой код

```
cout << "Enter price: ";
                cin >> num;

                it = trees.begin();

                for (auto& t : trees)
                {
                    if (t.getPrice() == num)
                    {
                        trees.erase(it);
                    }
                    it++;
                }
```

Прерывает компиляцию, выдает ошибку. Что не так ? Возможно, я не правильно делаю ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых, вы не определяете тип для `it` (нужно `auto it` = ...  или правильный тип вместо auto ). Во вторых, как только вы удаляете элемент, итератор становится недействительным(это итератор для конкретного контейнера, а контейнер теперь другой, в частности имеет другой размер). Этих двух причин достаточно, чтобы переписать код.
Можно использовать `std::remove_if`  или `std::partition` для перемещения таких элементов в конец, а потом от возвращаемого алгоритмом итератора и до конца вектора удалить все элементы. Можно это делать в простом цикле:

```
size_t sz = trees.size();
for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    if (trees[i] == num) {
        trees.erase(trees.begin() + i);
        --i;
        --sz;
    }
}
```

Или,  как сказал выше:

```
trees.erase(std::remove_if(trees.begin(), trees.end(),
    [num](const auto& el) { return el.getPrice() == num}), trees.end());
```

Есть конечно много другие варианты, например:

```
decltype(trees) v_true, v_false;
std::partition_copy(trees.begin(), trees.end(),
    std::back_inserter(v_true), std::back_inserter(v_false),
    [num](const auto& el) { return el.getPrice() != num; });
trees = v_true;
```

Но я бы использовал предыдущий или варианты предложенные от `HolyBlackCat`

Comment: Можете показать в виде кода ? Я не совсем понял как нужно переписать

Comment: Кажется в первом варианте не хватает `i--;` при удалении элемента, так что если подряд идут две елки с нужной ценой, вторая не удалится.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, кажется вы правы, я слышком быстро написал...

Answer (score 2):

Еще варианты, в дополнение к соседнему ответу.

Классический:

```
auto it = trees.begin();
while (it != trees.end())
{
    if (trees[i].getPrice() == num)
        it = trees.erase(it);
    else
        it++;
}
```

С++20:

```
// Вместо `Tree` - тип, который хранится в векторе.
std::erase_if(trees, [&](const Tree &t){return trees[i].getPrice() == num;});
```

Comment: кажется  в первом варианте  итератор опять же  станет недействительным

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Точно, сам же на этом прокололся. :) Исправил.

Comment: С++20: еще не изучал, но давно думал почему не делают это возможным...

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое оберуть remove в erase. Банальный пример на int. С классом все будет работать)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


int main() {

    std::vector<uint64_t> vec{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3};

    std::copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << '\n';

    vec.erase(std::remove(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), 1), std::end(vec));

    std::copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```